# Issue while attaching file using <asp:FileUpload> control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am facing a weird issue while attaching file in my asp.net application.
I am using   control. belowis the piece of code which is used for uploading the file. why is weird coz,some time  File(.doc, .docx,.xls, .xlsx) is  getting attached/uploaded but some time a diffrent file os same time throwing error "404-file or directory not found".
In case of file getting upload when I tried to debug the code it control goes to server side code whereas In case of not getting upload, control does not passing to server side and simply throws my application customize error page or "404-file or directory not found". One thing I like to add that customize error page error throws when file is greater than 10 MB and 404-error thrown when file size greater than 30 MB. i am not validating file size anywhere is client side.

Comment: Is there a posibility that your upload times out so the file is not actually uploaded, thus you are getting the 404 error?

Also, try formatting your questions better.

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a limit to the maxrequestlength.

Try adding the following to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="99999999"/>
```